how can I add a complete MFC dialog app as a child dialog of another MFC app
I am using VS 2022. I have a working C++ multithreaded MFC app A (modal) and a separate working (modal) C++ single threaded MFC app B. I would like to use B as a means for both dialog A and its child thread to display dialog B windows (at various times, but always sequentially similar to using afxMessageBox) to gather information (B is displayed, gathers its data and closes when the user clicks a button, returning to either the main thread or the child thread). B should NOT persist, because the child thread of A posts information to the main thread to update A's display, so A's window should not become obscured by stale information in B. I started by making a copy of the Solution of A. I then did Project >> add >> existing item to insert copies of all the files from the Solution for B. I quickly got in trouble with multiple definitions of IDR_MAINFRAME and other elements. So I understand there can only be one main dialog. I am just unclear of how to make B a child of A from the existing code and the C++ classes it creates.
I think I need to cut the pieces of B (classes, resources, code to manage B, etc.) that belong in my A dialog and its child thread and paste them there, adding only B-related pieces of the Message Map from the headers.

Can't you make B a dll?

The original B has only one functionality (only one button which cycles its colors on each click). I need multiple buttons, with different text, colors and actions that can be determined at runtime. I want to use it's classes and code as a basis for such a dialog (simple example: green background for go and red for stop). Think of it as an enhanced AFXMsgBox.

These can all be implemented in a dll (MFC dll, with common memory management with the MFC executable), or even as a static library, if it is about to be used in multiple projects - if it's going to be used in a single project (the project you are currently developing) it doesn't need to be in some "library" form at all. Don't understand why you want to make it an application (executable); will it be possible to run stand-alone?

The code I have already runs standalone. As I mentioned in my previous comment, it has only ONE capability: display a window with ONE button and change that buttons

As is, the B app is really only an example of what its new button Class can do. I need to modify the B dialog (number of buttons and text fields) and make it display its window with a simple function call from A, similar to the way I am using afxMessageBox.

Yes, but as mentioned above why does it need to be implemented as a separate executable (process)? This is actually impossible, due to the Virtual Address Space - you can't directly access data or call functions in another process, this requires employing mechanisms like interprocess communication or remoting. You should instead make it a dll, exporting that AfxMessageBox()-like function, or even a static library (.lib) that can be linked into project A. Or, if A is the only project using the feature, it could simply be included into the project.

After a lot of searching and head-scratching, I decided I needed to make the B window a child window of A instead of keeping it as a separate app. This way, I can show/hide the B window as needed and avoid the overhead of app startup for B.
